# Asignar dato a un atributo ignore en Realm

Tags: android, realm

Tengo un adaptador de RecyclerView donde mando como parámetro una lista de un objeto, lo que deseo es que al seleccionar un item settear un boolean la posición seleccionada, he creado un campo **ignore** que es un boolean.

Esta es la clase:

```
 public class Category extends RealmObject {
    private String sfid;
    private String name;
    private String bigImageId;
    private String smallImageId;

    @Ignore
    private boolean selected;

    /*get
     *set
     */
   }


public class CategoriesRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesRecyclerAdapter.MyHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Category> categories;
private Button btnSearch;
public List<String> categoriesSfid = new ArrayList<>();

public CategoriesRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Category> categories, Button btnSearch) {
    this.context = context;
    this.categories = categories;
    this.btnSearch = btnSearch;
}

@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_category, viewGroup,false);
    return new MyHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder myHolder, int i) {

    myHolder.txtTittle.setText(categories.get(myHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName().toUpperCase());
    if(categories.get(i).getBigImageId()!=null) {
        Util.loadImage(context, categories.get(myHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getBigImageId(), myHolder.imgMoment, R.drawable.grey_circle, R.drawable.grey_circle);
    }
    myHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(categories.get(myHolder.getAdapterPosition()).isSelected()){
                categories.get(myHolder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(false);
                myHolder.txtTittle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.text2));
                myHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.view20));
                categoriesSfid.remove(categories.get(myHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getSfid());
            }else{
                categories.get(myHolder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(true);
                myHolder.txtTittle.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
                myHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.tycColor));
                categoriesSfid.add(categories.get(myHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getSfid());
            }


        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categories.size();
}

public static class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTittle;
    ImageView imgMoment;
    LinearLayout lyCategory;

    private MyHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        txtTittle = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_tittle);
        imgMoment = v.findViewById(R.id.img_moment);
        lyCategory = v.findViewById(R.id.ly_category);
      }
   }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que el campo no está "setteando", osea no cambia de false a true ni true a false.

Comment: Debes usar el valor de i, que es la posición y no usar myHolder.getAdapterPosition().

Answer (score 0):

El segundo parametro del método `onBindViewHolder()` es la posición del elemento, en base a este valor puedes obtener el elemento en la lista de objetos.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder myHolder, int i) {
```

Por lo tanto puedes obtener las propiedades del objeto en la lista mediante este valor, como ejemplo para obtener el nombre del respectivo objeto:

```
//No usar categories.get(myHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName(); 
categories.get(i).getName();
```